# How packet from remote ip reaches local process

Tags: networking, tcp

This question may seem silly .But I am really struggling to find the answer...
I am currently working in a project where a local process receives data from remote ip in a predefined port... No firewall is there ... I have checked the iptables..
My question is how packet from a remote  ip get forwarded to local process listening on a port on a local loop back interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up https://www.cubrid.org/blog/understanding-tcp-ip-network-stack, Data Receiving chapter.